# replace null value to N/A in left join using laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I know in sql using IFNULL I can replace null value. But i need this using laravel eloquent and also not use raw sql query in laravel eloquent.

```
public function testQuery() {                                                       
    $dataList = SpeechModel::leftJoin('speech_subtitle', 'speech_title.speech_title_id', 'speech_subtitle.speech_subtitle_speech_id')->get();                                     
    return $dataList;                                                                                            
}
```

### output

```
speech_title_id=null,speech_subtitle_id=null,speech_subtitle_text=null
```

Comment: Seriously I donot understand what the problem is and what you expect perhaps I can help. You want to find a model where a particular field is null?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DB::raw()` in the `select()` method:

```
    $dataList = SpeechModel::select(
            '*', 
            DB::raw('IFNULL(speech_subtitle.speech_subtitle_speech_id, "N/A") as subtitle')
    )
    ->leftJoin(/*...*/)
    ->get();
```

This method lets you use Query Builder while using a raw statement in the `SELECT`. You could do this for every column.

But, honestly, if this is only about swapping `null` for `N/A`, you might consider doing it on the frontend instead.